# How to return a 401 from a REST Response

Tags: asp.net, rest

I have a REST API that I want to create an AccessToken for, but I want to be able to return a 401 if the user does not provide the correct credentials, but I can't seem to figure/get the 401 to return instead of the AccessToken

So this is the basics of my code (using vb.net)

```
<WebInvoke(method:="POST", UriTemplate:="auth/token/",BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
Public Function Token() As _AccessToken

    Dim myAccessToken As New _AccessToken  'class to return to the user
    Dim Authenticated As Boolean = False
    Dim objRequest As HttpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request
    Dim Username As String = objRequest.Headers("username")
    Dim Password As String = objRequest.Headers("password")


    Authenticated = AuthenticateUser(Username, Password)

    If (Authenticated = True) Then

        'Set the access token
        myAccessToken.ID = "sadfsdv32234fdgdg"

     Else

         HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 401
         HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = True
         HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
     End If


     Return myAccessToken

End Function
```

I'm figuring the issue is because I have declared my return type to be _AccessToken I have to return that type, but I also figure there must be a way to override this, but not sure how.

Comment: use `HttpResponseMessage` as the return type of your op.

Comment: I'm limited to .net 4.0 (company restriction) and that only came along in 4.5.

Comment: consider `ActionResult `.

Comment: By changing my return type to System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult stops me returning my _AccessToken class when I do have a valid request, so I'm not sure how that helps?